# Android avd Manager and Sdk.exe not opening

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-virtual-device, java-6

Just a few days back my sdk and avd was working perfectly but now it has stopped opening at all . I tried running the exe file but only for a small fraction of time cmd windows opens and closes and nothing happens.

My environment variable:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;**
has the following path. 
Tried Where Java in cmd n I got these two things:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe**

Everything seems to be right .still my avd and sdk does not work. I tried reinstalling it again. Also downloaded the bundle for sdk also but still to no avail.

Comment: Try the solutions mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181998/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-does-not-launch-on-windows-7-x64)

Answer (score 1):

i have also experienced similar problem, after too much of struggling i ended up with reinstalling latest java and android sdk. now its working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you:

1) To verify if your Java JDK run without problem, after that

2) To use the new android skd, now it include all in one zip file,

3) To test launch your appli in a new emulator android

Good luck